# Azure devops cicd my sql release pipeline failing

Tags: mysql, azure-devops, release

I have created "Azure mysql db deploy" task , i have selected the subscription but in server list i dont find the server and the release pipeline is failing with the following error.

2023-11-07T21:39:13.3361713Z ##[error]Error: The MySQL server list is empty. The MySQL server host name is invalid.

I tried creating different service connection but that also did not help

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Is there any update about this ticket? Feel free to let me know if the answer can give you some help?

Answer (score 0):

Refer to  this doc: [AzureMysqlDeployment@1 - Azure Database for MySQL deployment v1 task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/azure-mysql-deployment-v1?view=azure-pipelines&viewFallbackFrom=azure-devops)

> The Azure Database for MySQL Deployment task only works with Azure Database for MySQL Single Server.

Currently, the built-in Azure mysql db deploy task only supports MySQL Single Server.

By default, when you create the Mysql db on Azure Portal. It is Flexible type.

So the task will not be able to connect to Flexible type Mysql Server.

**Note:**  Flexible type Mysql Server is the Recommendation type. MySQL Single Server will be deprecated

I am afraid that there is no out-of-box task can be used to deploy to Flexible type Mysql Server in Azure DevOps for the time being.

For a workaround, you can use the mysql command to do the deployment to Flexible Mysql Server.

For example:

```
- task: CmdLine@2       
  displayName: Run SQL Scripts in MySQL database
  inputs:
  script: 'mysql --host=$(mysql-server) --user=$(mysql-user) //
      --password=$(mysql-password) -D $(mysql-database-name) //
      --execute="source path/to/script.sql"'
```